# Flutter doctor can't locate iOS SDK 17.0 on Mac despite installation

Tags: flutter, xcode, flutter-doctor

I'm experiencing an issue with Flutter where 'flutter doctor -v' can't locate the iOS SDK 17.0 installed on my Mac, and instead, it's looking for SDK for iPhoneOS16.4. I've confirmed that I have iOS 17.0 installed. Can anyone help me identify and resolve this issue? Here are the details:

**Environment:**

- macOS: 14.0
- Xcode: 15.0
- Flutter: 3.13.7
- Dart: 3.1.3

**Issue:**
When I run 'flutter doctor -v,' I receive the following error message:

```
Error executing simctl: 72
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.plOS.plOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.4.sdk" cannot be located.
```

**Steps Taken:**
I have already tried the following steps:

- Installed iOS SDK 17.0 through Xcode.
- Checked that my Xcode path is correctly set: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
- Reset the Xcode path.

What I haven't tried:

- Uninstall and reinstall Flutter.

How can I make Flutter recognize the installed iOS SDK 17.0 correctly and resolve this issue?

Your help is greatly appreciated, and any insights on making Flutter recognize the installed SDK version would be valuable. Thank you!